# when mapping cone is contractible

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It is quite obvious that if a map is a homotopy equivalence, then its mapping cone is contractible, but is the converse true: mapping cone contractible => the map is a homotopy equivalence? I am thinking about both the topological category and the category of chain complexes.

Comment: The mapping cylinder of $f:X\to Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$. The mapping _cone_ is contractible if (but not only if) $f$ is a homotopy equivalence. If $f$ is nullhomotopic then the mapping cone is homotopy equivalent to $Y\vee\Sigma X$.

Comment: It looks like maybe you made a typo when asking your question.  My guess would be you switched "cylinder" for "cone" and "null homotopy" for "homotopy equivalence" ?  I frequently say "cone" when I mean "cylinder" and I don't know why. 

Comment: Thanks to Tom and Ryan for corrections. Sure I meant a completely different thing when asking my question; I meant mapping cone and I meant a homotopy equivalence. I am curious to see an example of a map which is not a homotopy equivalence, but its mapping cone is contractible. Especially in the category of chain complexes.

Notice that a map is a quasi-isomorphism iff its mapping cone is acyclic.

Comment: Note that to get such an example you need to stay away from differential objects (i.e. $A$ with $d:A\rightarrow A$ s.t. $d\circ d = 0$) since for those $f$ is a homotopy equivalence iff the mapping cone is contractible. See: http://books.google.com/books?id=KaXmMjwBulgC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=%22mapping+cone+is+contractible%22&source=bl&ots=kvxLiy84Yn&sig=xvW64C4vVYnogvfMtt6idpaf-Po&hl=en&ei=l7VWTqyDMIHs0gHO44itDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22mapping%20cone%20is%20contractible%22&f=false

Comment: Another comment: if you end up getting an example from topology, stay away from the case when $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected CW complexes. According to exercise 9 in section 4.2 of Hatcher, that's a case where the mapping cone being contractible implies the map is a homotopy equivalence

Comment: David, thank you for the 2 great comments! Chain complexes is a partial case of differential objects, thus one should have Contractible cone => homotopy equivalence in this case. but for spaces i would still like to see a counterexample.

Comment: @Eric. I don't quite understand your example. May be you mean $N_G(H)=H$? otherwise $H$ can be just the trivial subgroup, in which case $BH$ is also a point.

Comment: I don't think your example works. First, the higher homotopy groups of the mapping cone are not so easily related to the homotopy groups of the initial spaces, thus I doubt $\pi_n(BG\cup CBH)$, $n\geq 2$, are trivial. If your example was true then for any inclusion $H\subset G$ of groups with $H$ simple the induced map in the homology $H_*BH\to H_*BG$ must be an isomorphism (it is easy to show from the long exact sequence that a map is a quasi-isomorphism iff its mapping cone is acyclic), but now take any finite simple group and take its different Silov subgroups, you see this can not work. 

Comment: Yeah, you're right, $(X, A)$ and $(X \cup CA, *)$ are different objects, so the long exact sequence of the pair doesn't say what I wanted it to.  I don't follow your last argument about the homology of simple groups, but this is enough to break it anyway.  I'll delete my comments in a short while to avoid confusing anyone who comes across this question later.

Comment: Ryan: I, too, am prone to saying "mapping cone" for "mapping cylinder". I think that, for me at least, the reason is that in the special case when $Y$ is a point the mapping cylinder of $f:X\to Y$ is called the cone on $X$. And that in the general case if you think of $X$ as an object in the category of spaces over $Y$ and think of the mapping cone of $f$ as another such object then the latter is a "cone" in that category: the mapping cylinder is a fiberwise cone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, going off my second comment from above, in exercise 9 from section 4.2 Hatcher gives a hint that solves your problem. Let $X$ be an acyclic CW-complex which isn’t contractible (I'll give an example below to be complete). Let $f: X \rightarrow *$. The mapping cone of this is $SX$, the suspension of $X$. Exercise 8 of section 4.2 proves that $SX$ is contractible because $X$ is acyclic. But the map $X \rightarrow *$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

Solution to Exercise 8: Suppose $\tilde{H}_*(X)=0$. From $H_0$ we see $X$ is path connected, so $SX$ is simply connected. Thus $H_* (SX) = 0 $ . By the Hurewicz theorem $\pi_*(SX)=0$ so $SX$ is contractible as desired.

An acyclic CW-complex which is not contractible (thanks to [link](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~3021009/algebraictopology/exercisesheet5.pdf))... Let $a$ and $b$ be the two loops in $X=S^1 \vee S^1$. Glue in two 2-cells along the words $a^5b^{-3}$ and $b^3(ab)^{-2}$. Then $\pi_1(X) = \langle a,b|a^5b^{-3},b^3(ab)^{-2}\rangle$ and this surjects onto the symmetry group of a regular dodecahedron (so $\pi_1(X)\not \cong 0$) while $H_1(X)$ is trivial because it's the abelianization and playing with symbols lets you reduce those relations to $H_1(X) \cong \langle a,b | a,b\rangle \cong 0$. It's clear that $H_n(X)\cong 0$ for $n>1$ because of the dimensions of the cells involved.

Comment: sorry, is the space $X$ from this example $K(\pi, 1)$?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer addresses the version of the question for topological spaces. But there is also a positive result for triangulated categories: a morphism $f \colon X \to Y$ is an isomorphism if and only if any distinguished triangle $X \to Y \to Z \to X[1]$ has $Z \cong 0$. See Tag [05QR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05QR).

This in particular applies to the homotopy category $K(\mathcal A)$ of chain complexes with values in an additive category $\mathcal A$, which is a triangulated category by Tag [014S](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014S). Applying this to the mapping cone in $K(\mathcal A)$ shows that $C(f)$ is contractible if and only if $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

This also applies to the *stable* homotopy category of spectra, where it implies that a map of topological spaces $f \colon X \to Y$ with contractible mapping cone is a stable homotopy equivalence.

In examples like David White's answer, you only need to go up to the first suspension $\Sigma X$, by construction (but see also [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/207802/82179)). I'm not sure if something like this is supposed to be true in general, but I'm guessing it's more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Weibel: An Introduction to Homological Algebra, Exercise 1.5.10 (1994 edition) asks you to show that for $C,C'$ split complexes with splittings $s,s'$ the cone on a map $f: C \to C'$ is split by the map $(c,c') \mapsto (-s(c),s'(c')-s'fs(c))$ if and only if the induced map on homology $H(f): H(C) \to H(C')$ is zero.